# How to run ASP.Net project pass through proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, web-config

I am was unable to run the asp.net project on my localhost when enable the internet proxy.

Already put this code on web.config:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
  <proxy
    proxyaddress="http://192.168.2.129:808"
    bypassonlocal="True"
  />
</defaultProxy>
```

But still unable to display my project on the browser. Its shows:

[image]